# Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error. (No Error??)

Tags: plugins, debug

I am having the error while trying to activate a plugin.

> "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error."

I set `WP_DEBUG` true from `wp-config.php` file, but there is no other error msg.

How can I find what is causing this issue?

Comment: Most servers have a PHP error log which will explain more. The location and name of the log varies by host; best to ask them where you can find error logs.

Comment: @WebElaine I use go daddy, and in the error log section, there is no item related to this case.